# Evaluate two-dimensional function in octave

Tags: octave

How can I evaluate a two-dimensional function in octave?

When I have a function which looks like this in WolframAlpha notation:

```
f(x, y) = {{x^2-y^2}, {x^2-y}}
```

(Matrix with one column and two rows)

I would like to evaluate it at any point like this: `f(1, 0)` which should give me the result `{{1}, {1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. using a function handle:

```
f = @(x,y) [x^2 - y^2; x^2 - y];
f(1,0)
```

Read the manual section on the syntax for creating matrices [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-Examples.html#Creating-a-Matrix)